# "Exception: La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo" al enviar por email los cambios ocurridos en Google Sheets mediante Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tenía un script funcionando hace casi dos años sin ningún problema hasta ayer. Lo que hacía este script (sin ningún problema hasta ayer) era escuchar los cambios en una Hoja de Google, recoger los datos de la fila que había cambiado y enviarme un correo electrónico con esos datos.

Pero el mismo ha empezado a fallar desde ayer con el siguiente error:

> Error Exception: La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo.
> at onChange(Código:5:31)

Esta es mi función `onChange()`:

```
function onChange(e)
{
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var mData = activeSheet.getRange("A"+activeRow+":D"+activeRow).getValues()[0];  
  var firstName = mData[1];
  var lastName = mData[2];
  var eMail=mData[3];
  

  if (addUsertoGroup(eMail))
  {
    sendConfirmation(eMail);
    Logger.log("Enviado: "+eMail);  
  } else {
    Logger.log("NO Enviado: "+eMail);  
  }
}
```

#### Depuración

Para ver lo que podría estar ocurriendo, he dejado la función así:

```
function onChange(e)
{
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  Logger.log("Sheet: "+activeSheet+"\nRow: "+activeRow);
}
```

Y sigue dando error:

> Error Exception: La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo.
> at onChange(Código:4:31)

Al parecer, el problema está en el código que detecta la fila activa para recoger sus datos. Ignoro si Google ha cambiado la forma de hacer esto y necesito de su ayuda para poder hacer funcionar de nuevo mi código.

Comment: @NicolasOñate ese reporte es del 7 de septiembre, el código me funcionaba hasta ayer. Es una gestión de suscripciones y hay varias suscripciones diarias por lo que debió haber fallado hace días. De hecho en la Hoja de Google hay entradas nuevas creadas, pero no he sido notificado de las mismas por correo. ¿Qué versión me sugieres que actualice?

Answer (score 1):

En relación a la depuración de un activador instalable usualmente result útil registrar las propiedades del objeto evento:

```
function onChange(e)
{
   Object.keys(e).forEach(key => console.log(JSON.stringify(e[key]));
   // Agrega aquí lo demás que deseas intenta
}
```

Según entiendo para el caso que estas probando debería `changeType` debería ser igual a `"EDIT"`, si no fuera así, esta seguramente la explicación del problema, si lo fuera, en lugar de

```
var activeRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
```

intenta con

```
var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
```

si lo anterior no funciona, intenta con

```
var activeRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
```

Lo anterior porque en ocasiones no funciona encadenar métodos a métodos del tipo `getActive...`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. En este caso sólo me interesa escuchar cuando una nueva fila es insertada en la Hoja, no cuando hay ediciones (creo que son dos cosas distintas). Por otro lado, me cuestiona que esto haya dejado de funcionar de repente, cuando llevaba funcionando bien hace casi dos años. [He expuesto el caso en el Issue Tracker de Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200577812) porque sospecho que esto podría ser un bug o algún cambio en la API de Google. Al parecer lo van a revisar en el equipo encargado de Sheets API.

Comment: No hay de que. Gracias por compartir el enlace al reporte. Ojala respondan pronto. P.D. Encontré un reporte similar que menciona getActiveCell https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67794501. Al momento no tiene  estrellas ni comentarios.

Comment: Parece ser un error parecido, aunque ese reporte es del 2017 y no recibió ninguna respuesta. En mi reporte al menos han respondido diciendo que lo pasarán al *team*, así que *wait and see*. Ya informaré cuando esto se resuelva.

Comment: Efectivamente, la solución era cambiar `getActiveCell()` por `getActiveRange()` tal y como indicas al final de tu respuesta. Sugiero que edites, dejando solamente eso del final para evitar confusiones, pues [según me indicaron en Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200577812#comment3) las nuevas filas de la Hoja se capturan con `getActiveRange()`. Espero tu edición para marcarla como aceptada y de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Te agradezco mucho la consideración. En este caso me parece que lo correcto sería publicar otra respuesta y lo justo sería que tu lo hicieras porque publicaste el *issue* y tuviste la fortuna de tener una respuesta muy pronto que además te sirvió.